# Accessing foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False, null=False)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False, unique=False)

class Shared(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)

class SharedMap(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Shared)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Now I execute the following query:

```
def get_shared_feed(self):
    return Article.objects.filter(shared__sharedmap__receiver=self)
```

And I actually get the list of articles as expected. However:

```
{{ article.shared_set.count }}
```

Gives me more than 1 if the articles was shared before. I want to get the list of articles with a single sender(e.g. friend) for each. Instead, I receive the list of articles with the set of every user that shared this article.

Comment: You can either write a helper method on `Article`, or a template tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was really easy. I just had to specify fields I want to return using values:

```
blog_feed = Article.objects.filter(shared__sharedmap__receiver=self).values('title', 'rating', 'shared__sender')
```

Then on the template:

```
{{ article.shared__sender }}
```